# Defining equivalence of categories without using functors

Tags: category-theory, foundations

Equality of functors is dangerous. While it technically is possible to ask whether two functors are equal in foundations like ZFC Set Theory, this might violate the principle of equivalence, and thus should be avoided. But functors are supposed to be the maps between categories, and equivalence of categories is often defined in a way that depends on functors. This, i feel might be a source of a lot of bad intuition for newcomers to category theory like me, who might be misled into thinking of categories like algebraic structures, when actually their maps are in a sense weaker (for example, it doesn't really make sense to ask about the cardinality of a category since equivalent categories can have different cardinality).

One alternative way to define equivalence of categories in ZFC, without using functors is by using skeletons. Unfortunately this requires choice. What are some other ways to define equivalence of categories in more general settings (like intuitionistic set theory) without using the notion of a functor?

Comment: I'm confused. Where do we use equality of functors in the notion of equivalence of categories? This is a good argument against _isomorphisms_ of categories, but equivalences only requires the composite of functors to be the identity up to an _isomorphism_ of functors, not an equality.

Comment: A good concept is that of an anafunctor, though this has some minor issues as well. Also a good option is using homotopy type theory, which permits one to consider isomorphisms as equalities.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor We don't. It just feels strange to define functors before equivalence of categories to me, since before having  a notion of equivalence of categories we don't have equivalence of functors, so in this timespan that a new person is starting to learn about category theory, they're misled into thinking wrongly about functors (thinking about equality of them).

Comment: I guess I disagree. An equivalence should be, in particular, a way of comparing two categories. That is, a functor. So it makes sense to me to introduce functors first. To the first of your two points I would say that we _do_ have an equivalence of functors before we have a notion of equivalence of categories -- that is, natural isomorphism. In fact, the usual definition of equivalence of categories _relies_ on this equivalence of functors.

Comment: To the second I would say that it's not the end of the world if people first think about equality of functors, only to later be told that really equality isn't as helpful a notion as we might like. Learning math is a lot of unlearning old analogies and ideas. There's a famous quote that's relevant here: "When teaching math, it's important to teach the truth, nothing but the truth, but _never_ the whole truth". I see nothing wrong with letting people think about equality of functors until they're ready to learn about natural transformations. Typically, this happens pretty quickly anyways.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor However, i'm trying to get into category theory and i'm not satisfied by how the default way motivates things. I find it hard to motivate why natural transformations should be defined the way they are, and am looking for a different perspective that might shed a different light into all this.

Comment: @ZFCarla How do you think natural transformations should be defined differently?

Comment: I don t think you have to through equality out of the window, just because categories (and especially higher categories) allow to weaken the equal sign. Even homotopy type theory has a concept of judgmental equality (equal by definition). Category theory is a completely normal field of mathematics, nothing esoteric about it. You do not need to warp your mind to learn it. If you like to read more conceptual text, then 'Conceptual mathematics' and 'A gentle introduction to category theory' by peter smith are good choices.